# lodash.js select like mysqls `in`

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, lodash

I'm using lodash.js to filter my json value. I need something like Mysqls "in" function in Lodash.

```
json value:
[
{id:1,customer:5},{id:2,customer:6},{id:3,customer:6},{id:2,customer:7}
]
```

I want to select `"customer in(6,7)"` in lodash. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lodashes [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) function on collections.

```js
const input = '[{"id":1,"customer":5},{"id":2,"customer":6},{"id":3,"customer":6},{"id":2,"customer":7}]';

const mysqlIn = (json, array) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(json);
  let ans = _.filter(data, function(x) {
    return array.includes(x.customer);
  });
  return ans;
}

console.log(mysqlIn(input, [6,7]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @YavuzŞeker great. Please upvote/accept the answer if it worked for you